# X Y Conversion to lat lng

Tags: c#, google-maps, maps, proj4js

i have places location in the database by x ,y and shape 
How can I convert this location points to latitude and longitude pairs?
Is there a tool or a formula?

for example x =220162.636213404 y = 762057.914609313 it should be something like 
    lat = 34.55667500000000000 lng = 31.68173300000000000

Thanks!

Comment: Where are x and y are measured relative from? i.e. where is x=0, y=0 in your database?

Comment: i got a sql that insert the data to my db the columns names are pt_x_map and pt_y_map

Comment: What are the units of X and Y?  Meters? Pixels? Something else? What location corresponds to (x,y) = (0,0)?  From the values you've posted, this looks like a rather unusual coordinate system -- we'll need more information in order to help you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different geographic coordinate systems. The most commonly used is WGS84 ([EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/)). Google Maps uses it's own spherical mercator projection which is commonly known as Google Mercator, but its latlong values are WGS84 coordinates.

In order to transform your coordinates you have to know the source and destination coordinate system. Once you have figured this out you can use a library like [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) to calculate the transformation.

[Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) also provides an online coordinate calculator, which might help you to figure out which coordinates system the coordinates in your database are using.

If you are looking for a C# framework: [SharpMap](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpMap) is great for handling all aspects of geospatial applications.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the [projection model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) you choose to use.

Comment: And where in the world your data is.

Answer (score 0):

Asumming x, y are pixel-measured positions, you could adapt this snippet:

```
> public Class MyMapView extends MapView {
```

> .... 
>      /**
>       * x,y are screen coordinates.  The location l is set to the
>   latitude and longitude that corresponds to this
>       * point on the screen.
>       */
>      public void setLocation(double x, double y, Location l) {
>           double latSpan = (getLatitudeSpan() / 1.0E6);
>           double lngSpan = (getLongitudeSpan() / 1.0E6);
>           Point center = getMapCenter();
>           double xPcnt = x / ((double)getWidth());
>           double yPcnt = y / ((double)getHeight());
>           double lat0 = (center.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 + (latSpan/2.0));
>           double lng0 = (center.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 - (lngSpan/2.0));
>           double lat = lat0 - (yPcnt * latSpan);
>           double lng = lng0 + (xPcnt * lngSpan);
>           l.setLatitude(lat);
>           l.setLongitude(lng);
>       } 
>   ...

Taken from: 
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/f40fa714555c9617

Comment: The sample x and y values given are greater than 100 000. If those are pixel coordinates, avnic's got quite a big screen